# Passive FTP connecton not working on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, ftp

I'm trying to configure my FTP in Windows Server 2012, but when I try to connect using FileZilla, it responds **Failed to retrieve Directory Listing**.

When I try to connect using Windows Command/ftp, that uses an active connection, I can retrieve the directory listing.

Than I'm assuming there's something strange with my passive mode configuration.

I already specified the external IP in the FTP Firewall Support of server node.
I already restarted FTP Service and also rebooted the server.
I already run netsh commands suggested by microsoft to open Firewall ports.

What am I'm missing?

I'm on a cloud server and I have full control over the machine.

Comment: First test is to try to connect to the FTP server from the server itself.

Comment: I found the problem. I was trying to configure the firewall direct in server by remote access, but my hosting provider offer a firewall configuration in its panel and I need to allow ports there.